# How can I Copy link address in chrome developer tools in Network tab for multiple files

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I open a Chrome Devtools and choose Network tab. Then I can choose "Copy link address" if I right-click on some file (they are image files in my case) in the request list.
I want to get their addresses in one click (or as easy as possible).
Is there a good way or a workaround for that?

Comment: I guess you could write an extension that uses [chrome.devtools.network](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools_network).getHAR or simply use the built-in `Copy all as cURL` context menu command and then extract the urls in your text editor with a regexp (that can be automated with a macro).

Comment: @wOxxOm I can't see 'Copy all as cURL' option. Only 'Copy all as HAR'. 'Copy all as cURL' would be a nice option.

Comment: I am afraid, if you check once again you'll find out that there is "Copy as cURL", but not "Copy all as cURL" :)

Comment: It was [added on July 27th](https://codereview.chromium.org/2177383003) and [included in the current Chrome 53.0.2785.105](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/53.0.2785.105/third_party/WebKit/Source/devtools/front_end/network/NetworkLogView.js#1361) (Stable channel) that was released two days ago.

Comment: Hmm.. I have Version 53.0.2785.116 m, and I still don't have that :(

Comment: @AndrewAnderson, Btw note that <Copy all as HAR> has no response data, just the headers.

Answer (score 2):

click`"Copy" >> "Copy all as HAR"`on any item in the network tab (preferably under URL column but it shouldn't matter).

go to console, below and place the cursor. you will be typing something there now.

type ```a=

you have stored the clipboard in a variable just now.

press `enter`
type `copy(a.log.entries.map(e => e.request.url).join('\n'))` and press `enter`
check your clip board.

if you are too lazy for all that you could just run a .py script like this:

```
import csv , os, sys, json
import pyperclip

output_file = 'output.csv'
sdata = pyperclip.paste()
try:
    j = json.loads(sdata)
except Exception as ex:
    print(f'Exception .. {ex}')
    sys.exit()

entries = j.get('log').get('entries')
allurls = [entry.get('request').get('url') for entry in entries]

with open(output_file, 'w', newline='', encoding='UTF-8') as fp:
    writer = csv.writer(fp)
    for url in allurls:
        writer.writerow([url])

print(f'output file {output_file} created for {len(allurls)} URLS!')
```